# iPhone Xcode 4 picker Data source

Tags: ios4, xcode4, uipickerview, sigabrt

This seems a somewhat silly question to ask, but since upgrading to Xcode 4, a technique i use often does not work. I am taking about setting the data source for a Picker within a .xib

Previously it was a case of declaring the following in the header file...

```
 @interface testViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {

    UIPickerView *singlePicker;
    NSArray *pickerData;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *singlePicker;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *pickerData;
```

Then setting up the data source within in the main 'viewDidLoad', as such...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Small", @"Medium", @"Long", nil];
    self.pickerData = array;
    [array release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

And then connecting the File's Owner to the picker, and the pickers datasource, and delegate outlets to the File's Owner, but when I connect the datasource outlet of the picker to the File's Owner i get a SIGABRT error before the app loads...

Can anyone explain this to me? I don't understand as projects i have previously built in Xcode 3 using this method compile and run fine in Xcode 4, but any new projects i try to make do not work?

Many thanks

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, you now have to include the following functions within the implementation file...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [pickerViewArray count];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [self.pickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

It works now!